# Need to disable Auto Preview in views for local development in settings.php

Tags: views, 8

Can I add a setting in settings.php to disable Auto Preview in views. I know this can be changed under /views/settings/. But I don't want this configuration added to Git. I only want this change on my local site. Something like this.

```
$config['system??']['foo']['bar'] = FALSE;
```

I unchecked 'Automatically update preview on changes' in Views settings and exported the changes. The result is that it updated  'views.settings' Below is part of views.settings.yml

```
     ui:
      show:
        additional_queries: false
        advanced_column: true
        master_display: true
        performance_statistics: false
        preview_information: true
        sql_query:
          enabled: true
          where: below
        display_embed: false
      always_live_preview: false
      exposed_filter_any_label: old_any
```

The setting may look something like this.

```
$config['views.settings']['ui']['always_live_preview'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Did you set it off and export to see what changed?

Comment: Good idea, I did not. I will edit my post and add this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, make sure you clear cache:

```
$config['views.settings']['ui']['always_live_preview'] = 'false';
```